# document.getElementById returned undefined for all inputs in a form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do some calculations with some form inputs but all the element (checkbox,text etc) returned undefined when I tried to get their value using `document.getElementById('income').value`.

[image]

Comment: Please post the form code.

Comment: Please post code as TEXT...

Comment: Not everyone can see images and they make it more difficult to help you. Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You should have an input with that id to make that JavaScript code work.

```
<input id="income">
```